# Can I block on the opponent's side?

Tags: rules, volleyball

Is it legal to block the ball on the opponent's side? That it, the stricken ball reaches my hands before it reaches the net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the blocker can reach over the net to block the ball.  However, blockers are not allowed to interfere with an opponent's play.  Essentially, this means that the blocker is not allowed to touch the ball until an opponent has made an attack hit.

The rules on blocks are found in Chapter 14 of the [FIVB Official Volleyball Rules](http://www.fivb.org/EN/Refereeing-Rules/RulesOfTheGame_VB.asp), which are the rules used in Olympic play.  Section 14.3 covers Blocking Within the Opponent's Space:

> In blocking, the player may place his/her hands and arms beyond the 
>   net, provided that this action does not interfere with the opponent’s 
>   play. Thus, it is not permitted to touch the ball beyond the net until an 
>   opponent has executed an attack hit.

Comment: Does this mean that you can make such an overreaching block only after third touch, or is for every attack hit (I am not sure that "attack hit" is actually defined)